# Maharal on Avodas Hashem

Tags: tefilla, sources-mekorot, torah-study, maharal, avodath-hashem

The Maharal (in Gur Aryeh in the beginning of Bereishis) says, "Our avodas Hashem through Torah and Tefillah that's how we bring forth the kavod Hashem." That's the purpose of creation is to increase honor heaven.

Avodah is reference to Torah and Tefillah. We serve Hashem through davening. What greater honor can we show Hashem, then the fact that we are his servants? Our lives are dedicated totally in the service of Hashem. If that's where the honor of Hashem comes from, then if we G-d forbid, are מזלזל in our Tefillos, avdus and honoring Hashem, r"l פרניעות.

Does anyone know where the Maharal in Bereishis say this?

Comment: Is this whole thing a quote you remember or heard, or is only the quoted part from the Maharal and the rest is yours?

Comment: @HaLeiVi: It's from [HaRav Yitzchok Sorotzkin](http://www.kvodshomayim.org/audio/Stop%20the%20Talking%20in%20Shul%20%20Rav%20Yitzchok%20Sorotzkin%20on%20Kedushas.mp3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably referring to this, on the first Rashi [(Gur Aryeh)](https://www.sefaria.org/Gur_Aryeh_on_Bereishit.1.1.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).

> ז] בשביל ישראל והתורה. בב"ר (א, ד). ויראה לומר מה שנברא העולם בשביל אלו ב' דברים, דכתיב (משלי טז, ד) "כל פעל ה' למענהו", רוצה לומר כל מה שנברא בעולם בשביל הקב"ה נברא ולכבודו נבראו (יומא לח. ), "כל הנקרא בשמי לכבודי בראתיו" (ר' ישעיה מג, ז), ואין כבוד מן הנבראים אלא כאשר יקיימו את מצוותיו ועובדים אותו, ואין זה רק באומה הישראלית, ועליהם נאמר (שם שם, כא) "עם זו יצרתי לי תהלתי יספרו", שלכך יצרתי אותם כדי שיספרו תהלתי, וישראל אינם עובדים להקב"ה אלא במצוותיו שמקיימים את התורה, וזה בשביל ישראל ובשביל התורה נברא העולם, וכל שאר העולם נברא בשביל ישראל

Comment: Please send me a link to this.